# iOS App architecture implementing MVVM, Networking and Bluetooth, how?

Tags: ios, mvvm, bluetooth, swift2, rx-swift

#### Problem:

I am currently facing a problem with developing an iOS Mobile Application in `Swift` that utilizes:

- `BTLE`: Connecting to a peripheral device and sending/receiving data to/from it.
- `Networking`: If the peripheral is connected to a network (wireless and/or ethernet), then the communication over `BTLE` "could" instead happen over the network.
- `Model-View-ViewModel` architecture
- [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift)

#### About the App:

It starts with a **Bluetooth Setup** view, which walks the user through the process of pairing with the peripheral device (disjoint from the `TabBarController`).

After successfully pairing with the device, all configuration is requested by the iOS App from the device, which is sent as `JSON`.

This `JSON` contains the different `Model` information (programming) that the App displays to the user for manipulation and needs to be stored in a array somehow in a `Singleton` manor to where a `view-model` can request any index for displaying to the user.

After all the data is received, the **Bluetooth View** dismisses and the **TabBarView**'s are presented.

#### Current Examples:

A good example to relate this App to would be the `Apple Watch` and the correlating iOS App that allows you to configure everything. I am having to do somewhat the same concept.

Another good example app from this [blog post](http://twocentstudios.com/2015/12/08/an-experimental-ios-architecture-based-on-radical-decoupling/) where they are doing something similar to what I am trying to achieve. The difference I am running into though, is their dependency injection setup for MVVM (as well as other similar examples). I've used a storyboard, where as they have programmatically instantiated their view controllers in the `AppDelegate`.

#### And my problem...

How can I pass the data (efficiently) from **BluetoothView** to **TabBarView** without `NSNotifications` or `PrepareForSegues`? Keeping in mind that I am intending to use the library [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) for asynchronous event handling and event/data streams. I am trying to keep this App as stateless as possible.

Are the `Servers` in this [blog post](http://twocentstudios.com/2015/12/08/an-experimental-ios-architecture-based-on-radical-decoupling/) a good practice for retrieving `view-models` and/or updating them?

Comment: Pass data using a delegate protocol.

Comment: @sschale But the BTLEViews and TabBarView are decoupled, they don't know about each other. And doesn't delegate passing only work backwards? This would technically be a "forward" movement. I am trying to make it as test-able as possible while remaining in MVVM architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that, when using RxSwift, the "view-model" ends up being a single pure function that takes observable parameters from the input UI parameters and returns observables that are then bound to the output UI elements.

Something that really helped me wrap my head around Rx was the [tutorial videos for cycle.js](https://egghead.io/series/cycle-js-fundamentals).

As for your specific conundrum...

What you are doing doesn't have to be "forward" movement. Look at it this way... The TabBarView needs some data, and it doesn't care where that data comes from. So give the TabBarView access to a function that returns an observable which contains the necessary data. That closure will present the Bluetooth View, make the connection, get the necessary data and then dismiss the Bluetooth View and call `onNext` with the required data.

Looking at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dtartaglia/b92163d6055e1a580d493676e5b1e448) might help get across what I'm talking about. Granted the gist uses PromiseKit instead of RxSwift, but the same principle can be used (instead of `fulfill`, you would want to call `onNext` and then `onCompletion`.) In the gist, the view controller that needs the data simply calls a function and subscribes to the result (in this case, the result contains a UIImage.) It is the function's job to determine what image sources are available, ask the user which source they want to retrieve the image from and present the appropriate view controller to get the image.

The current contents of the gist are below:

```
//
//  UIViewController+GetImage.swift
//
//  Created by Daniel Tartaglia on 4/25/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 MIT License
//

import UIKit
import PromiseKit


enum ImagePickerError: ErrorType {
    case UserCanceled
}

extension UIViewController {

    func getImage(focusView view: UIView) -> Promise<UIImage> {
        let proxy = ImagePickerProxy()
        let cameraAction: UIAlertAction? = !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) ? nil : UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .Default) { _ in
            let controller = UIImagePickerController()
            controller.delegate = proxy
            controller.allowsEditing = true
            controller.sourceType = .Camera
            self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        let photobinAction: UIAlertAction? = !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.PhotoLibrary) ? nil : UIAlertAction(title: "Photos", style: .Default) { _ in
            let controller = UIImagePickerController()
            controller.delegate = proxy
            controller.allowsEditing = false
            controller.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
        if let cameraAction = cameraAction {
            alert.addAction(cameraAction)
        }
        if let photobinAction = photobinAction {
            alert.addAction(photobinAction)
        }
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        let popoverPresentationController = alert.popoverPresentationController
        popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.bounds
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        let promise = proxy.promise
        return promise.always {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            proxy.retainCycle = nil
        }
    }
}


private final class ImagePickerProxy: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    let (promise, fulfill, reject) = Promise<UIImage>.pendingPromise()
    var retainCycle: ImagePickerProxy?

    required override init() {
        super.init()
        retainCycle = self
    }

    @objc func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let image = (info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage) ?? (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)
        fulfill(image)
    }

    @objc func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        reject(ImagePickerError.UserCanceled)
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response thank you. Let me see if I can sum up what you've said. Basically leave the `TabBarController` as the `InitialViewController` and when it "loads", call the closure to present the `BluetoothViewController` which would return the necessary data. Is it safe to assume the same same "setup" would work with network communications (wrapping a closure function to return the data as well)?

Comment: Certainly. Whether asynchronous data comes from the user or the network, the same idea will work fine. RxCocoa already has methods for retrieving data from the network. Another good article about Rx http://yarikx.github.io/NotRxJava/